# Is it possible to pass arguments to a decorator while calling a function in Python?

Tags: python, function, decorator

Does anyone know if it's possible to pass arguments to a decorator while calling a function in Python ?

Until now, I only saw that at function definition :

```
@decorator("This is a decorator", 66)
def func(a: int, b: int) -> None:
    pass
```

But I was wondering if it was possible to do it while calling a function.

For those who are wondering why I want to do this, it's because I'm proceeding someone else's work who used decorators a lot in his code. But until now he only had to pass arguments at function definition because the function was only called once. The decorators are used to print information logs about the context the function is used but in my case, since the function can be called at different places, the context can be different in function of where the function is called.

Comment: Your reasoning is not clear, please provide a [mcve]. The short answer is "no" since decorators are applied at definition time

Comment: The decorators don't "exist" by the time the function is called. Decorators replace/augment the function definition by returning a new function. I think you'd need to have the decorator make use of a global state that can be affected by calling the function or something similar. I don't think that's generally a good idea though.

Answer (score 9):

As others wrote here, a decorator is a syntactic sugar (i.e., makes programs easier to read, write, or understand) of a function that receives another function as a parameter and activates it from inside.

So, calling this “Add()” function with the decorator, like this:

```python
@wrapper()
def Add(x: int, y: int):
    return x + y
```

It is just like calling the “wrapper” function with the “Add” function as a variable. Like this:

```python
 wrapper(Add)(x,y) # pass x,y to wrapper that pass it to Add function.
|wrapper|
|----Add----|()
```

The best way (I think) to add parameters to a decorator, is by nesting it all under another function that holds a child decorator. For example:

```python
@deco_maker(msg: str)
def Add(x: int, y: int):
    return x + y
```

will be this:

```python
 deco_maker(msg)(Add)(x,y)
|--wrapper-|
|-wrapper_func-|
|---------Add-------|
```

Here is a simple wrapper decorator that log's function calls, without parameters, which can look like this:

```python
def wrapper(func: Callable):
    def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
        logging.DEBUG f"Function '{func.__name__}' called with args: {[str(arg) for arg in args]}."
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return value
    return wrapper_func
```

and here is the extended decorator with relevant logging parameters (log name and level for more flexibility):

```python
def log_func_calls(logger_name: str, log_level: int):
    def wrapper(func: Callable):
        def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
            logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
            logger.log(
                    level=log_level,
                    msg=f"Function '{func.__name__}' called with args: {[str(arg) for arg in args]}."
                    )
            value = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return value
        return wrapper_func
    return wrapper
```

Here is a full code example for a parameterized decorator for logging function calls, and the log file output print after it.

**Example**:

```python
import logging
from typing import Callable

# define app logger with file and console handlers
def setup_logging():
    logger = logging.getLogger('test_app')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # create file handler which logs even debug messages
    fh = logging.FileHandler('test.log')
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # create formatter and add it to the file handler
    formatter = logging.Formatter('{asctime} | {name} | {levelname:^8s} | {message}', style='{')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    # add the handler to the logger
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    return logger

# define a log decorator to trace function calls
def log_func_calls(logger_name: str, log_level: int):
    def wrapper(func: Callable):
        def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
            logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
            logger.log(
                    level=log_level,
                    msg=f"Function '{func.__name__}' called with args: {[str(arg) for arg in args]}."
                    )
            value = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return value
        return wrapper_func
    return wrapper

# sample usage 1
@log_func_calls(logger_name='test_app', log_level=logging.DEBUG)
def Add(x: int, y: int):
    return x + y

# sample usage 2
@log_func_calls(logger_name='test_app', log_level=logging.DEBUG)
def Sub(x: int, y: int):
    return x - y

# a test run
def main():
    logger = setup_logging()
    logger.info("<<< App started ! >>>")
    print(Add(50,7))
    print(Sub(10,7))
    print(Add(50,70))
    logger.info("<<< App Ended ! >>>")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the log output:

```text
...
2022-06-19 23:34:52,656 | test_app |  DEBUG   | Function 'Add' called with args: ['50', '7'].
2022-06-19 23:34:52,656 | test_app |  DEBUG   | Function 'Sub' called with args: ['10', '7'].
2022-06-19 23:34:52,657 | test_app |  DEBUG   | Function 'Add' called with args: ['50', '70'].
...
```

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is **no** but you can modify the code of the decorator function; for example:

```
def decorator(func):
    def inner(*args,**kwargs):
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
    return inner
```

this is a standard decorator function, let's change it a little.

you could do something like this:

```
def decorator(func,defaultdescription,defaultnum):
    def inner(description=defaultdescription,num=defaultnum,*args,**kwargs):
        print("function",func.__code__.co_name,"with description",description,"with number",num)
        return func(*args,**kwargs)

    return inner
```

so you can change the description of the function

Answer (score 0):

Basically a decorator is a function inside another which calls your function after it's completion. if you are planning to use your own decorator, you must have a inner function which does it's desired task and calls the function which used the decorator function. you can use *args and **kwargs

below code is a basic implementation of the python decorator

```
# Python code to illustrate
# Decorators basic in Python

def decorator_fun(func):


def inner(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    do your actual task here
    """
    for argv in args:
        print(argv)

    for key in kwargs:
        print(key)
    #returning to  function which used the decorator at last
    func()
    
return inner

@decorator_fun
def func_to():
    print("Inside actual function")

func_to("hello",{"test": "value 1"})
```