# Better code to return arguments passed to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-decorators

I've cobbled together some code that will return the name of a function and its arguments using a decorator. Here it is:

```
import inspect

def log(func):
    def inner(*s):
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
        w = "Function: " + func.__name__ + ", " + \
            "arguments: " + str(s)
        return w
        
    return inner

@log
def greet(msg):
    "Greeting message: " + msg

t = greet("abc", "def")
print(t)
```

My questions/observations are:

1. I realised too late that I could just refer to `s` directly in order to display the values of the arguments. This means that the lines that the first two assignment statements of `inner(*s)` are redundant; nonetheless, is there a more elegant way of getting the arguments out if I had to use that approach?
2. I've had to refer to `func.__name__` to get the name of the wrapped function because an unqualified `__name__` returns `__main__` (in this case). Also, if you write a function `c()` that invokes a function `b()` that invokes a function `a()` that displays `__name__`, it will still display `__main__` instead of a. What's the workaround for this?

Thanks.

`Function: __main__, arguments: ('abc', 'def')`
instead of
`Function: greet, arguments: ('abc', 'def')`

Comment: You should post this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Regarding the last sentence "x instead of y" - is that what you want, or what you get? which is which?

Comment: btw `__name__` is the name of the current module, not the current function.

Comment: You never use `args` or `values`. What's the point of calling `inspect.getargvalues()`?

Comment: You only need to use the `inspect` module if you want to access frames further up the call stack dynamically. You can definitely simplify by removing that stuff.

Comment: To make your decorator more general, the inner function should use `*args, **kwargs`.

Comment: If you are planning to use `t` for logging purposes, the `logging` module is already capable of displaying the name of the function where a log function is called, using `%(funcname)s` in the format string of the logger in question.

Comment: rather than `*s` I would use `*args, **kwargs` as that is a little more conventional.

Comment: Also, it's not clear why your decorator logs the function and its arguments *instead* of calling the function, rather than doing so *in addition to* calling the function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to pass arguments to a decorator while calling a function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72363990/is-it-possible-to-pass-arguments-to-a-decorator-while-calling-a-function-in-pyth)